# In MySQL, select one row out of multiple rows based on condition, otherwise select first row and exclude the rest

Tags: mysql, sql

I am interested in MySQL of writing a query that looks through a list consisting of IDs and locations.  Each ID represents a unique person who can be tied to multiple locations.

I have the following table to simplify things:

```
+----+----------+
| ID | Location |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Bldg#1   |
|  1 | Bldg#2   |
|  2 | Bldg#3   |
+----+----------+
```

I am looking to deduplicate the above table to only end up with ONE row per ID, but I would also like to add a conditional that preferences Bldg#1 for any given ID.  In other words, given a table of multiple rows with potentially the same ID and multiple locations, I would like to write a query that outputs 1 row per ID, and if any of the rows associated with that ID also have a location of Bldg#1, I want to keep that row and drop the rest. Otherwise, I just want to keep one arbitrary location row for that ID.

For the above table, I would like the following as output:

```
+----+----------+
| ID | Location |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Bldg#1   |
|  2 | Bldg#3   |
+----+----------+
```

Comment: @forpas good call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` with a `case` expression:

```
select id, location
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by (case location when 'Bldg#1' then 1 when 'Bldg#2' then 2 when 'Bldg#3' then 3 else 4 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This does not assume any particular ordering -- such as alphabetical ordering.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by id and use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
  case 
    when max(location = 'Bldg#1') then 'Bldg#1' 
    else any_value(location)
  end location 
from tablename
group by id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oRfhhJNUcF7mucVw7yXv1b/1).
Results:

```
| id  | location |
| --- | -------- |
| 1   | Bldg#1   |
| 2   | Bldg#3   |
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this you looking for?

Exmaple:

[image]

Query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEST
CREATE TABLE #TEST (ID INT, Location NVARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #TEST 
SELECT 1,'Bldg#1'
UNION
SELECT 1,'Bldg#2'
UNION
SELECT 2,'Bldg#3'

SELECT ID,Location FROM (
SELECT ID,Location, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS RNM
FROM #TEST) T
WHERE RNM = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

inner query will make sure the location is in order so that Bldg#1 is always the first for each id, so then the outer group by will pick the first record

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT id, location
    FROM location
    ORDER BY id, location ASC
)a 
GROUP BY id
```